# Resize subview according Aspect ration

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have a subview of size 1024*768, and I want to use this subview in both the version in iPhone build and iPad build. I have used both the property autoresizesSubviews,autoresizingMask. But still it is not fully showing on iPhone. How can I resize this larger view to according iPhone size ? Please check attached images.

[image: Large Image need to show this view into iPhone app]

[image: currently showing iPHONE]

Comment: Please study auto-layout and AutoResizing

Comment: I know but I am stuck. If  you can then please help me

Comment: Are you using storyboard or nib? if it is a nib you can make one for the ipad and one for the iPhone, regarding the storyboard i'm not sure